# How to take regex as parameter in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

script.sh

```
v1=$1
v2=$2
v3=$3
echo $v1 $v2 $v3
```

Run:

```
$sh script.sh "*.txt" "*.xml" "com*.jar"
```

- ***So if my current working directory*** have **abc.txt** and doesn't have any .xml or .jar file then output it's printing is,

```
abc.txt *.xml com*.jar
```

What I want to get in those variable is,

```
*.txt *.xml com*.jar
```

'cause if later script I want to run find command....

Any help I'll appreciate... Thanks in advance!...

Comment: `echo "$v1" "$v2" "$v3"`

Comment: FYI these are not regular expressions, they're shell wildcards.

Comment: Also see [Bash Pitfalls #14 (echo $foo)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).